# Prove the following statements about the geometric sum.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, induction

Prove the following two statements:

1. $\Sigma^n_{i=0}q^i=\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}, n \in \mathbb{N}, q\neq1$
2. For a number $q$ with $|q|<1$, $\Sigma^ ∞_{i=0}q^i = \frac{1}{1-q}$ is true.

The first part is easy to prove. I simply used induction with a base case of $n=0$. However, I'm having trouble with the second part. How do I even go about proving it?

Comment: Isn't the second part supposed to be a summation from $0$ to $\infty$ (not $n$)? If so, just take the limit $n \to \infty$ on both sides of your first statement.

Comment: If $|q|<1$, then $0<|q|^n<\dots<|q|^2<|q|<1$, for every $n\in\Bbb N$. It means that $|q|^n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thats why in the first part, the term $q^{n+1}$ "vanishes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} q^n = 0$ when $|q| < 1 $, then we observe that

$$ \sum_{i \geq 0 } q^i = \lim_{i \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^i q^k = \lim_{i \to \infty} \dfrac{ q^{i+1} - 1 }{q-1} = \dfrac{-1}{q-1} = \boxed{ \dfrac{1}{1-q} } $$